# Struggling to insert values into a new column

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am facing a problem. I have created a new column in my csv file and I am trying to add values in the column but don't know what functions to use. The column is called 'Discounted_Price' and I have to mentioned that for Ford and Chevrolet, the prices have a ten percent discount.
This is the code up to this point:

```
CarPrices_discount=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Jon\\Desktop\\data science\\car_prices.csv')
CarPrices_discount
CarPrices_discount.insert(15,'Discounted_Price',np.nan)
CarPrices_discount.head()
Ford_Chev=CarPrices_discount[(CarPrices_discount.make=='Ford')|(CarPrices_discount.make=='Chevrolet')]  
#Ford_Chev['Discounted_Price']=Ford_Chev['sellingprice']*0.9
CarPrices_discount.loc[CarPrices_discount.Ford_Chev['Discounted_Price']=Ford_Chev['sellingprice']*0.9
```

I know the last line is wrong but I do not how to insert it with dataframe.loc.

Comment: Welcome. can you explain what are the values you want in the new column?

Comment: @EitanRosati Yes, I am trying to add discount prices into the new column.

Comment: So only Ford and Chevrolet will have discount when the other not right?

Comment: The others also have a discount of 20% but I am resolving the ford and Chevrolet one first.

Comment: Ill send you the code. what is the column name of the auto company(Ford,...)?

Comment: column name is make.

Comment: Use `loc` here complicate things. I think is better to use the `apply` method. because if you not select all the columns the new column values will be `NaN`

Comment: I have never used apply.

Comment: If you can send me the the order of your columns and their names I can show you how to do it(If no, my code won't help)

Comment: year make model trim body transmission vin state condition odometer color interior

Comment: seller mmr sellingprice Discounted_Price saledate

Comment: I wanted to send the file to you but don't how to

Comment: You tried the other guy option?
`CarPrices_discount['Discounted_Price'] = CarPrices_discount.apply(lambda x:x.sellingprice*0.9 if x.make in ['Ford', 'Chevrolet'] else np.nan, axis=1)`

Instead of your 2 last code lines?

Comment: Yes, I tried it but it didn't work. Either way, I created an alternative: Ford_Chev=CarPrices_discount[(CarPrices_discount.make=='Ford')|(CarPrices_discount.make=='Chevrolet')]
print(Ford_Chev) Ford_Chev['Discounted_Price']=Ford_Chev["sellingprice"]*0.9
print(Ford_Chev)

Comment: Though it looks quite awful and gives an warning but it gives the desired outuput.

Answer (score 0):

Data:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> CarPrices_discount = pd.DataFrame({"make" : ['Chevrolet', 'a', 'b', 'Ford', 'Chevrolet', 'Ford'],
                                       "sellingprice" : [900, 10,20,20,40,30]})
>>> CarPrices_discount

    make        sellingprice
0   Chevrolet   900
1   a           10
2   b           20
3   Ford        20
4   Chevrolet   40
5   Ford        30


>>> CarPrices_discount['Discounted_Price'] = CarPrices_discount.apply(lambda x:x.sellingprice*0.9 if x.make in ['Ford', 'Chevrolet'] else np.nan, axis=1)
>>> CarPrices_discount
    make        sellingprice    Discounted_Price
0   Chevrolet   900             810.0
1   a           10              NaN
2   b           20              NaN
3   Ford        20              18.0
4   Chevrolet   40              36.0
5   Ford        30              27.0
```

Comment: I used a csv file so I am not sure if this would work or not...

Comment: His answer should work `CarPrices_discount['Discounted_Price'] = CarPrices_discount.apply(lambda x:x.sellingprice*0.9 if x.make in ['Ford', 'Chevrolet'] else np.nan, axis=1)`.
Try it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found an answer of some sort but it is highly flawed:

```
Ford_Chev=CarPrices_discount[(CarPrices_discount.make=='Ford'(CarPrices_discount.make=='Chevrolet')] print(Ford_Chev) 
  Ford_Chev['Discounted_Price']=Ford_Chev["sellingprice"]*0.9 
  print(Ford_Chev)
```

Comment: First of all the code in question seemed to have another problem. I would take this as an answer.

Comment: @b10n1k I don't quite follow... What was the problem?

Comment: you miss some elaboration. what was the initial problem that you found and how the followup answer actually solved it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."

Comment: @b10n1k Ohhh... I understand. Thanks for telling me